# viewcontroller using a NULL baseURL argument with the loadHTMLString baseURL method : data theorem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security, uiwebview

I am facing the problem "MyViewcontroller using a NULL baseURL argument with the loadHTMLString baseURL  method : data theorem"- i have successfully completed my task and all are working fine.

The Issue was in the OSWAP security scan for vulnerability it shows the above error.

My code snippet:-

```
  NSString *aHtmlString = kEmptyString;

    // Getting the bool from configuration plist
    NSString *thePlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *theURLdata = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePlistPath];
    is

ServerFAQAvailable = [[theURLdata valueForKey:kIsServerFAQAvailableKey] boolValue];

if (one || two || three) {
   aHtmlString = [self loadFAQFor];
} else {
  aHtmlString = [self loadFAQForwithout];
}
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePlistPath];

[self.faqWebView loadHTMLString:aHtmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

**Update:**

```
if (one || two || three) {
       aHtmlString = [self loadFAQFor];
    } else {
      aHtmlString = [self loadFAQForwithout];
    }
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"about:blank"];

    [self.faqWebView loadHTMLString:aHtmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Still shows me scan issue

Comment: I would start by logging the values of `thePlistPath` (and possibly `theURLdata`), and verifying that you actually have a file at the location pointed to by `thePlistPath`.  If you don't, then `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePlistPath];` will likely return nil and `theURLdata` will also likely be nil.

Comment: what is `ee`, `yy` and `ii` ? please use clear variable names, also what's the values of `kConfigurationPlistName` and `kPlistFormType` ? does that set the value of `thePlistPath` properly or is it Nil ?

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg hi that is the condition based variables in the loadFAQForewithout inside i am constructing the html .js and .css file

Comment: Two days only there i am available on next 48 hours . anybody need more information means feel free to ask . any hint will be help full .

Comment: have you tried just passing `[NSURL new]` in `baseURL` param.

Comment: @SunilSharma no it will give null only by printing that statement you can able to see that . Any other tries feel free to post .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the `baseURL:` parameter. BaseURL isn't needed for an html string, it is usually used for relative links. If all you're trying to do is show some html, are you sure you need it?

The security issue flagged makes sense (my understanding, roughly): If a webview's baseURL is set to the local file system, then a page loaded (eventually) through that webview could access local resources.

Try passing nil for `baseURL:` should silence this warning.

Comment: Related url in that means What ? Could you please provided details

Comment: Relative path in the sense ?..., this is also relative path right  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"about:blank"]

Comment: you have any suggestion on about giving relative path

Comment: @Spynet ("about:blank" --I'm not sure how UIWebView handles that.) Regardless, a relative link is relative to the base URL. On the normal internet, if a webpage starts at "website.com/about" the BaseURL would be website.com and a relative link would be "/services"--don't need full address. 

But a URL can be for files and a base URL to the local directory. In this case, the webview gets special permission to read local files. If that html links to an external page, the UIWebView will still have that permission, and (apparently) that page could read local files-- this is the security issue.

Comment: If do you want relative local-directory links, to get around the security issue you could implement the webview delegate and intercept clicked links, recreating the full relative path. If all you want to do is show local html, you don't need a base URL and set it to nil.

Comment: no it is also give problem, i tried before then only i asked

Comment: "sorry this is not right one " can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: which one is correct ?  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"about:blank"] or [NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]  . Stack overflow is not just the book of reference but it is the solution for the programmers.

Comment: Lastly i found the right answer is [NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"], Thanks a lot for the help man.

Answer (score 1):

baseURL should be [[NSBunld mainBunld] bunldPath], you can try like this..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.htmlName ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Comment: Lastly i found the right answer is [NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"], Thanks a for the help man